# Python создание csv файла

Tags: python, csv

Создаю `csv` файл для учета картриджей

```
import csv

with open('cartridge_accounting.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Date', 'Model', 'Mark'])
    filewriter.writerow(['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print'])
    filewriter.writerow(['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print'])
```

в итоге файл записывается с пропуском через одну строку

```
['Date', 'Model', 'Mark']
[]
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
[]
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
[]
```

Подскажите как от этого избавиться. И как добавить индексный ряд, чтобы файл выглядел вот так:

```
['Date', 'Model', 'Mark']
[0,'2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
[1,'2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
[2,'2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
[3,'2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) советуют решать это так

```
with open('cartridge_accounting.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 2):

Для таких задач идеально подходит модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

columns=['Date', 'Model', 'Mark']

data = [
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print'],
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print'],
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print'],
['2019-02-26', 'CE255X', 'nv print']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv(r'/path/to/cartridge_accounting.csv')
```

результат:

```
,Date,Model,Mark
0,2019-02-26,CE255X,nv print
1,2019-02-26,CE255X,nv print
2,2019-02-26,CE255X,nv print
3,2019-02-26,CE255X,nv print
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, давно смотрел в сторону Pandas, и вот, как раз  удобный случай.