# Requests CSV. Сохранение файла

Tags: python-3.x, requests, csv

Требуется скачать файл с сервера и сохранить в том же формате как CSV

```
package = requests.get(url)
print(package.text)
```

str1
str2
str3
Header1, Header2
data11, data12
data21, data22
data31, data32

если я сохраняю так:

```
with open(file, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in pack:
        out_file.writelines(line)
```

то получаю в файле:

str1
str2
str3
Header1, Header2

data11, data12

data21, data22

data31, data32

если делаю так:

```
with open(file, 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.writelines(pack)
```

где pack = package.text

то питон пишет так

str1str2str3Header1, Header2
data11, data12
data21, data22
data31, data32

Comment: попробуйте так:`out_file.write(line)`

Answer (score 0):

частично помогло решение отсюда [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949997/python-создание-csv-файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949997/python-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)
итоговый код такой:

```
with open(file, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    for line in pack:
        out_file.writelines(line)
```